# Unexpected result in calculating payments

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of numbers that look like this:

```
[[    0.     771.98     0.   ...,   771.98     0.    1543.96]
 [ 1320.83  4782.33  1320.83 ...,  1954.45     0.    1954.45]
 [ 2043.61     0.    4087.22 ...,  4662.3   2907.82  1549.53]
 ..., 
 [  427.6      0.     427.6  ...,   427.6      0.     427.6 ]
 [  868.58  1737.16     0.   ...,   868.58   868.58   868.58]
 [    0.    1590.07     0.   ...,   787.75     0.       0.  ]]
```

I also have a vector of numbers that look like this:

```
0        771.98
1       1320.83
2       2043.61
3        736.03
4        948.03
5       1838.70
...
```

Now I need to take each row and divide by the the vector. In other words take `row1 = [    0.     771.98     0.   ...,   771.98     0.    1543.96]` and divide  the first element of the vector `771.98` which should yield this:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  5.  1.  0.  2.]]
```

I tried this:

```
payment = []
index = 0
for i in range(len(cpi)):
    payment = cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]
print(payment[:1])
```

But I get this:

```
[[ 0.          1.60983442  0.          1.60983442  1.60983442  1.60983442
   0.          8.04917212  1.60983442  0.          3.21966885]]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Following the answer provided I tried both suggestions. For the first suggestion I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3e5833506bde> in <module>()
      3 index = 0
      4 for i in range(len(cpi)):
----> 5     payment += cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]
      6 print(payment)
      7 # payment = np.divide(cf.T, cpi).T

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (1,11)
```

For the second suggestion I tried this:

```
payment = np.divide(cf.T, cpi).T
print(payment)
```

and I received this error:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f2ff3fa5409d> in <module>()
      4 #     payment += cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]
      5 # print(payment)
----> 6 payment = np.divide(cf.T, cpi).T
      7 print(payment)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
    480         """
    481         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index,
--> 482                                  copy=False).__finalize__(self)
    483 
    484     def __array_prepare__(self, result, context=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    246             else:
    247                 data = _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy,
--> 248                                        raise_cast_failure=True)
    249 
    250                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   3025     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
   3026         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
-> 3027             raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
   3028         else:
   3029             subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this result because you are re-assigning your `payment` in each loop. Try change `payment = cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]` to `payment += cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]`

As you added numpy to the tags I think an easier way would be using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape(-1,3)
# [[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]
#  [6 7 8]]
b = np.arange(3) + 1
# [1 2 3]
print(np.divide(a.T, b).T)
# [[0.         1.         2.        ]
#  [1.5        2.         2.5       ]
#  [2.         2.33333333 2.66666667]]
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not work, I get this error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (1,11)

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Sry I just saw that, for the first suggestion, you need to make sure `cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]` yields a list of list as you have written in your question. For the second suggestion, do you have both your cf and cpi numpy array the same dimensions as above? If not so please reshape them.

Comment: As you didn't mention what type and shape your `cf` and `cpi` are I have to guess from your question, perhaps you could give an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I could verify.